# What is wrong with this HTML, JavaScript and JSON code?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following HTML code in a file called `test.html`. Both the HTML file and the JSON file below are stored on a server within the same directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shape Up</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_get_json()
{
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "game.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
            results.innerHTML = "";
            for(var obj in data)
            {
                results.innerHTML += data[obj].title;
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
ajax_get_json();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It pulls data from a file called `game.json` which is stored in the same directory.

```
{
    "level_001":
    {
        "id":001,
        "title":"Level 1",
        "difficulty":0,
        "comments":"this is how you complete level 1"
    },
    "level_002":
    {
        "id":002,
        "title":"Level 2",
        "difficulty":0,
        "comments":"this is how you complete level 2"
    }
}
```

**The problem is that the `results.innerHTML = "";` line is never reached. Why?**

There are no errors in the browser, I've checked this on Firefox and on Safari.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Check if you allow local XMLHttpRequests!

Comment: No errors, and the files are stored on a server. (not local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) your JSON is invalid because of these properties:

```
"id":001
...
"id":002
```

You need to either remove the leading zeros:

```
"id":1
```

or make the numbers strings:

```
"id":"001"
```

For further details see the format rules spelled out at [json.org](http://json.org/)

Presumably the line you mentioned is never reached because `JSON.parse()` gives an error about the above. (Do you not see an error in the browser's console?)

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I'll accept the answer after 5 mins as per request of SO.